# pdb cannot debug into backward hooks

Tags: python, pytorch, pdb

Here is my code.

```
import torch
v = torch.tensor([0., 0., 0.], requires_grad=True)
x = 1
def f(grad):
    global x
    x = 2
    return grad * 2
h = v.register_hook(f)  # double the gradient
v.backward(torch.tensor([1., 2., 3.]))
h.remove()
print(v.grad)
```

When I debug with `pdb`, I find that I cannot break in function f (I set a breakpoint inside f at the statement `x = 2`).

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Note: if I use pycharm, I can break into the function. But on the remote server, I would like to use `pdb`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try `ipdb` https://pypi.org/project/ipdb/ instead of `pdb`.

Comment: Did you put `ipdb.set_trace()` where you want to debug? Does it go inside the debugger?

Comment: Okay, `ipdb.set_trace()` works but `pdb.set_trace()` also works. They both require source code modified, making me uncomfortable. After all, I think `debugging` shouldn't modify the code. Otherwise, it is just like `printf debugging`.

Comment: You can't debug on server without changing the code on server. If you want to step into the function you should press `s`.  I guess that was your problem.

Comment: And its not like printf debugging. How many printfs will you put in your code and the remove it?

Comment: Okay, I put the code `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` where I want to break. After debugging, `sed -i 's/\s*import pdb;pdb.set_trace()//g' **/*.py` removes these lines.